# 1.7 compiler compliance level is not yet supported in MyEclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to use the new switch statement with Strings in it that is possible in Java 1.7.
e.g.

```
    String str = "string";
    switch (str) {
         case "string" : 
             // do something
             break; 
    }
```

And I installed JDK 7 and changed the Preferences to use jre7 but i am unable to change the compiler compliance level to 1.7 from inside eclipse, the properties dialog has a drop down that goes only up to 1.6. Restarted the tool but did not see any changes. Now what should i do to udate the JDK to 1.7 in Eclipe
Thanks in adcance!!

Comment: why can't you original style of switch case?

Comment: what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Did you try the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545560/how-can-i-use-java-7-with-eclipse-indigo-3-7-1 ?

Comment: I am using MyEclipse 10.7

Comment: Yeah i have tried alot, but no way was answered...

Comment: Are you sure you have started the correct installation and not some older MyEclipse?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure that everything is installed OK, it is for two days that i am seachring the internet fot this problem, and also when i write the same code in a Notepad and compile it in MS_Dos it working well with no problem, but in MyEclipse it is not working.

Comment: My compiler compliance drop down has 1.7 in it. I suggest you reinstall MyEclipse after getting rid of all traces of the previous installation. I can only assume that, for some reason, an older eclipse base is being used.

Comment: "why can't you original style of switch case?" Never jump the gun to ask such questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is odd; MyEclipse 10.7 should support Java 7: [MyEclipse Java 7 Support](http://www.genuitec.com/blog/?p=3970)

There us a [detailed forum post](http://myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-28470.html) which says:

> MyEclipse **10.0.1** is now publicly available
>   ...
>   1) Built on **Eclipse 3.7.1, now supports Java 7.**

Comment: Yeah i also think that it must work with Java 7, but it does't now.

Comment: Look into the "plugins" folder of your eclipse install and search for `org.eclipse.jdt.core` and `.ui`. Which version do they have?

Answer (score 0):

Oh and as for your java question in you command line type java -version and that will probably answer your question. Find out what version of Java is installed and I think you need Indigo if you're going to use Java 7, I feel like I had an issue with that on Windows but I don't remember specifically. Update Java and Eclipse to the latest versions and you should be good to go. If you're running Linux I just stuck with Java 6.

Comment: Thansk you for your reply! I tesded the version of java installed in my machin with the same command line as you mentioned, and also i wrote the same code in notepad and compile it in command line when i run it, was working well, but in MyEclipse it not supported it is why also searched alot for that, but not find any answer yet :(